# How to add single quote with Regex php arrays

Tags: php, regex

For From

```
$data[ContactInfos][ContactInfo][Addresses]
```

to

```
$data['ContactInfos']['ContactInfo']['Addresses']
```

Comment: I dont see anything you have tried so far.

Comment: use **str_replace**, it will also work

Comment: why would you need to process your php with php?

Comment: i need to removed notices and warning ,thats why with one click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kU3GuB/1)):

```
(?<=\[)|(?=\])
```

PHP([Demo](https://eval.in/908869)):

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\[)|(?=\])/', "'", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

With this

```
preg_replace('/\[([^\]]+)\]/', "['\1']", $input);
```

Try it here

https://regex101.com/r/YTIOWY/1

Answer (score 0):

If you have mixed string - with and without quote, regex must be a little sophysticated

```
$str = '$data[\'ContactInfos\'][ContactInfo]["Addresses"]';
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\[)(?!(\'|\"))|(?<!(\'|\"))(?=\])/', "'", $str);
// result = $data['ContactInfos']['ContactInfo']["Addresses"]
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/908874)

Answer (score 0):

The first rule of regex: "Don't use regex unless you have to."

This question doesn't require regex and the function call is not prohibitively convoluted.  Search for square brackets, and write a single quote on their "inner" side.

Code ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/955798cf6d9affc49bf4a93442562e7f97d46e24))

```
$string='$data[ContactInfos][ContactInfo][Addresses]';
echo str_replace(['[',']'],["['","']"],$string);
```

Output:

```
$data['ContactInfos']['ContactInfo']['Addresses']
```

Comment: I agree with @JON